# Are these prepositions ("of motion") exact antonyms?

Tags: предлоги

Is the following correct?

- Whenever `в + (винительный падеж)` is used to mean something, `из` is *always* used to mean the opposite.
- Whenever `на + (винительный падеж)` is used to mean something,
  `с + (родительный падеж)` is *always* used to mean the opposite.
- Whenever `к` is used to mean something, `от` is *always* used to mean the opposite.

I.e. am I correct in understanding that `в + (вин.) / из`, `на + (вин.)/с + (род.)`, and `к/от` are exact antonyms of each other?

My question isn't about when to use a certain pair (which is complicated, but I believe I mostly have the rules down for that), just whether each is a valid antonym pair, as I have inferred.

Comment: I would say "yes", they are valid "antonym pairs", at least I cannot recall any exceptions to the formulated rules. If there are any, they are used very rarely

Comment: I came to the same conclusion but I know one case when this is not entirely true: sometimes there is a variation between из and с with no corresponding variation of в/на: пошел в поход, вернулся из/с похода.

Comment: @SergeySlepov "Пошёл в поход" -- "вернулся из похода", never ever "пошёл на поход", neither can we say "вернулся с похода".

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy, Never say never ;-) "С похода вернулось не больше половины казаков", "Входили в Рим колонны стройные, с похода возвращаясь на ведическую Русь" (Владимир Мегре), "В январе 1740 года вступила в столицу возвращавшаяся с похода гвардия" (Василий Авсеенко), etc. Just google "с похода" and you'll find thousands of examples.

Comment: I wonder if "c" can be seen in those examples as fast-spoken or vulgar-spoken degraded derivative from "из".  More like `'с` like `'tis` and `it's` from full `it is`

Comment: consider внутрь(внутри)/изнутри pair :-D  ( where-to inside, where-is inside, from-inside )

Comment: the kinda exceptions would perhaps stem from "switching the verb". Like "набег на Болгарию" -> "набежать на Болгарию" (there is no such a verb actually, but if it was...) and then "вернуться из Болгарии". The actions described are opposite, but since verbs are not direct antonyms the prepositions used are different.

Comment: correct tag would be [tag:предлоги] for приставка - prefix - is a part WITHIN the word, not another separate word :-)
Indeed, many times same.... morphemes?... are used as both prefixes and prepositions. Still terms are different :-D

Comment: @SergeySlepov 5990 results for "вернулся с похода", 34 600 for "вернулся из похода". Most results for the former seem to be from a translation of some Turkish movie.

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitry: Yes, that is what they call variation in linguistics. The minor variant (с похода) is statistically significant (1:6) which cannot be attributed to a spelling error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a native speaker, I couldn't find any exception quickly. I can presume that what you have written is true, those prepositions can be called "exact antonyms".

Answer (score 5):

This depends on your definition of antonym. Consider for instance:

> К трапу шла ковровая дорожка
>
> От трапа шла ковровая дорожка

Meaning essentially the same.

Comment: yep, it is when you looking at the same carpet from opposing (antonym :-D) ends thus in opposite directions :-D

Comment: @Arioch this can be said from the saqme position.

Comment: well, physically you do not have to move your body, indeed. But you describe the situation - spread of the carpet - as a virtual movement from point A to point B - or from point B to point A. This ordering of points makes the "virtual" views opposite. Not the situation itself, but the ordering of steps to paint it.

Answer (score 1):

> Whenever к is used to mean something, от is always used to mean the opposite.

In some meanings, but not all of them. E.g. consider:

> Мы должны закончить этот проект к октябрю.
>
> Литий относится к щелочным металлам.
>
> Она носит платья от Кардена.

Note that you can say also:

> Она носит платья к Кардену.

But those two would not be the opposite (in fact, in some, somewhat tortured, understanding of the situation, it may actually mean the same thing - that Cardin took part in manufacturing the dresses).

Also, second and third examples also broadly mean the same - classification, even though the former is by chemical properties and the latter is by brand.