# Does отходить/отойти include the moving by train?

Tags: грамматика, глаголы, разница

While learning on Memrise course (Top 10,000 words, Part 1), I found that отоходить/отойти shows the meaning of not only leaving by foot, but also leaving by train. The user-based Memrise course often includes the course creator's misunderstanding or typos, so I checked my dictionary, and found that отоходить/отойти also includes the meaning with "(a vehicle) depart(s) off a stop" (it is not English dictionary so I translated).

But there is also a verb that is used for 'going by vehicle', with 'ехать' family, in which case, отъезжать/отъехать. So if отоходить/отойти also has the meaning, what is the difference from отъезжать/отъехать and when to use the one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does отходить/отойти include moving by train?

No. But it can describe the movement of the train itself:

- Поезд отходит в 20:00. - The train leaves at 20:00.

(От)ехать is more akin to 'ride':

- Мы отъехали от города на 5 км. - We went (by transport) 5 km out of the city.

Simply put, the difference **идти/ходить** vs **ехать/ездить** is like 'move by oneself' vs 'ride'. Both animate (man) and inanimate (bus) things can move by themselves (**идти/ходить**).

There are a lot of edge cases which have been discussed in greater detail in this SO question:

- [In Russian, do vehicles walk?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/14790/2104)

Comment: Thanks. So the rule is inanimate objects can take отоходить/отойти as a verb yet animate objects cannot?

Comment: @Blaszard Animate objects that have feet or similar appendages can certainly отоходить/отойти.

Comment: @mustaccio I meant it such that animate objects cannot take отоходить/отойти as a verb when they go by vehicle. Of course they can take the verb when going by foot.

Comment: @Blaszard, please see my updated answer.